# How to integrate seam with jQuery

Tags: jquery, seam

Our project is developed with seam. Customer changes the UI and provided the UI prototype using jQuery. Now we are facing lots of trouble integrating jQuery into seam. Customer wanted more rich UI.

(1) How do I create modal-popup in seam. Any basic code??
(2) How do I call partial submit (or ajax call) using jQuery? In other words how do I invoke seam action from jQuery?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a breakdown of implementation techniques I found useful when enhancing existing Seam (2.x)+JSF web pages with UI Widgets from Javascript libraries like jQuery (would have put more hyperlinks, but I was limited to 2):

- **Import the jQuery Javascript library**

  - If you are using JSF (Apache MyFaces), for example, you can do this as would be done in HTML inside of an `<f:verbatim>` tag:

    ```
    <f:verbatim>
        <source src="..path to jQuery.."></source>
    </f:verbatim>
    ```
  - Or, a JSF component library, like Trinidad or RichFaces, will usually have a component for this purpose.  See [`<trh:script` (Trinidad)](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/trh_script.html) or [`<aj4:loadScript>` (RichFaces)](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/script.jsf).
- **Customize text (or behavior) displayed by jQuery UI widgets (dialogs, tabs, etc.) from Seam using EL**

  - A jQuery dialog could be rendered with a title and text from a Seam resource bundle:

    ```
    <div id="dialog" title="#{messages.dialogTitle}">
        <p>#{messages.dialogText}</p>
    </div>
    ```
  - EL can be used like this to render any HTML or Javascript with values from the Seam context.  This includes restoring state on the client side - see the jQuery UI tabs component example below.
- **Update State in Seam Components/Invoke a JSF Action**

  - Seam Remoting (http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html) allows any Seam component to be used directly in Javascript as if it were a Javascript object.  The documentation has instructions for how a request can even be done in the current Seam conversation.  An example use case is storing the state of the jQuery UI tab that was selected by the user so that the tab widget will re-open this same tab when the page is re-accessed in the same Seam conversation.

    ```
    // Get a reference to the Javascript proxy for the Seam component that
    // stores the selected tab state in the current Seam conversation
    var tabStateSeamComponent = 
        Seam.Component.getInstance("tabComponent");

    // Bind the tab select event to a function that updates
    // the selected tab in the Seam component
    $(function(){
        // Select the previously selected tab (or default) on
        // page load using the state stored in the Seam component
        $('#tabsId').tabs('select', 
                          #{tabComponent.getSelectedTab('#tabsId')});  

        $('#tabsId').bind('tabselect', 
            function(e,ui){
                // Seam remote calls will be made within the 
                // current Seam conversation
                Seam.Remoting.getContext()
                    .setConversationId( #{conversation.id} );

                tabStateSeamComponent.setState('#tabsId', ui.index);
            });
        });
    ```
  - If required, a form can be submitted with a JSF *action* (e.g. to integrate with Seam navigation rules) from Javascript by figuring out how a form submit button in your JSF component library implements a form submit.  For example, if you use Trinidad, use a `<tr:commandButton action="actionString" ...>` form submit button on a page and inspect the rendered HTML button in the source using Firebug or a similar tool.  Or, you could just render the button so that it is invisible (set CSS style to `display: none;`) and use jQuery to submit the form using the button (e.g. `$('#buttonId').click();`).  Your JSF component library may have a Javascript API to make programmatic form summit less of a hack.
- **Consider using Facelets to quickly package jQuery UI widgets as re-usable custom JSF components**

  - (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/) is a good (JSF 1.2) tutorial.
  - This would allow creating a modal dialog component with a tag interface like

    ```
    <custom:dialog title="#{message.title}" 
                   text="#{messages.text}" 
                   action="jsfActionString" />
    ```

    where the implementation is defined in a separate Facelet file and makes use of jQuery APIs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply wanting to create modal-popup and call a partial submit I'd suggest using the Richfaces tag library which you may already be using.

To create a modal dialog simply use the  tag to create the modal panel:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="myModalPanel" minHeight="100" height="100" minWidth="100" width="100" zindex="2000">
    Insert content for modal panel here
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Now you can add a  tag to a button or link to hide and show the modal panel:

```
<h:outputLink value="#" id="showLink">
    <rich:componentControl for="myModalPanel" attachTo="showLink" operation="show" event="onclick" />
</h:outputLink>


<h:outputLink value="#" id="hideLink">
        <rich:componentControl for="myModalPanel" attachTo="hideLink" operation="hide" event="onclick" />
</h:outputLink>
```

And to do an ajax call you would use the  tag inside the tag that you would like to make the ajax call.  So, for instance, if you wanted an action to fire when the text of a field changes you would do the following:

```
<h:inputText id="myField" value="#{myBean.myField}">
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onChange" reRender="list fields you want to rerender when the methods completes" action="#{myBean.methodToCall}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call seam components from jQuery via Seam Remoting. Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Go check out the component showcases of [icefaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/) and [richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/jbossrichfaces/), two jsf AJAX cable libraries.

Partial submit via icefaces:

```
  <ice:outputText value="#{myBean.myField}" />
  <ice:form>
     <ice:commandButton action="#{myBean.doSomethingToField()}" value="button" />
  <ice:form>
```

[modal popup](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface) with icefaces you can read more about here.

My personal experience with both: Richfaces mixed better with other jsf libs, icefaces has more advanced AJAX capabilities (like server sided push, kinda like comet) the basic AJAX functionality is easier to set up and use, but plays difficult sometimes when you mix it with other jsf libs. Both have different component libraries so be sure to check them out; you don't want to mix these libs later on.

Answer (score 0):

You should download jquery library and use `<a:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>` tag in your xhtml pages. and the most imported thing is user `"jQuery"` instead of `$`
or you can use `<rich:query` component. for ex. `:http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jQuery.jsf;jsessionid=482C2B4F2C9C2DCE10573E0A02D468A9?c=jQuery&tab=usage`